# Mysql returns result when no matching data

Tags: mysql, join, null, sum

Can anyone explain me why I'm getting the following result

**scenario** :
there are no data to match "WHERE B.t_id=1" condition in the tables. So it should not return any value. But it returns a result and from that you can see B.ts_id is NULL.

```
Table food_item  => one record : o_id=1
Table table_sale => one record : ts_id=1, But t_id=20
```

Why mysql returns a record like this?

```
SELECT A.o_id,B.ts_id,SUM(s_price) tot 
FROM tbl_food_item A, table_sale B 
WHERE A.o_id=B.ts_id  AND B.t_id=1
```

result

```
o_id  |  ts_id  | tot
----------------------
1       Null      Null
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the result (always get `NULL, NULL, NULL`). Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, e.  g. a fiddle.

Comment: yes, it should be all NULL, But in my PC it gives the wrong result

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 10.1.38-MariaDB

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7.  An empty result set is what I get.

Comment: @blabla_bingo: if you are selecting sum() and have no group by, there's no way it would return empty results; there will always be just one row returned.  5.7 fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6dfef9ffb423ef5ff3c9f2f4d5e7028f

Comment: @ysth Right you are. I actually skipped the aggregation function as `s_price` in `SUM(s_price)` wasn't given column value by the OP.  As I tested before, sum()  returns a null while count() returns a zero if the where clause does not hit when the `GROUP BY` clause is not used.  Thanks for the heads-up.